# PHP Array Goup using date with multiple keys and assign Sum of keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array, array-walk

I'm wring a PHP script to group some payment info using date. part of original array is like this.

```
 array(50) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Datum"]=>
    string(10) "2016-07-07"
    ["C"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Datum"]=>
    string(10) "2016-07-07"
    ["C"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Datum"]=>
    string(10) "2016-07-07"
    ["Paypal"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Datum"]=>
    string(10) "2016-07-07"
    ["Bank"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Datum"]=>
    string(10) "2016-07-12"
    ["C"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Datum"]=>
    string(10) "2016-06-13"
    ["C"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [6]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Datum"]=>
    string(10) "2016-06-13"
    ["C"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [7]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Datum"]=>
    string(10) "2016-06-13"
    ["Afterpay"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [8]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Datum"]=>
    string(10) "2016-06-13"
    ["C"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [9]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Datum"]=>
    string(10) "2016-06-13"
    ["C"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [10]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Datum"]=>
    string(10) "2016-06-12"
    ["C"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [11]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Datum"]=>
    string(10) "2016-06-13"
    ["C"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [12]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Datum"]=>
    string(10) "2016-06-13"
    ["C"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [13]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Datum"]=>
    string(10) "2016-06-13"
    ["C"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [14]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Datum"]=>
    string(10) "2016-06-13"
    ["C"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [15]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Datum"]=>
    string(10) "2016-06-13"
    ["C"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [16]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Datum"]=>
    string(10) "2016-06-13"
    ["C"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [17]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Datum"]=>
    string(10) "2016-06-13"
    ["C"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [18]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Datum"]=>
    string(10) "2016-06-14"
    ["Afterpay"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [19]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Datum"]=>
    string(10) "2016-06-14"
    ["C"]=>
    int(1)
  }
    }
```

I wrote some codes to group those by date. here is my code

```
//$shipment - this is the original array
    $array1 = array('C' => null, 'afterpay' => null,'paypal' => null, 'Bank' => null, 'Ideal' => null);
    $array2 = array();

    array_walk($shipment, function ($v) use (&$array2, $array1) {
        $a = $v['Datum'];
        if (!isset($array2[$a])) {
            $array2[$a] = $array1;
        }
        unset($v['Datum']);
        $array2[$a] = array_merge($array2[$a], $v);
    });
```

Output after grouping

```
Array
(
    [2016-07-07] => Array
        (
            [C] => 1
            [afterpay] => 
            [paypal] => 
            [Bank] => 1
            [Ideal] => 
            [Paypal] => 1
        )

    [2016-07-12] => Array
        (
            [C] => 1
            [afterpay] => 
            [paypal] => 
            [Bank] => 
            [Ideal] => 
        )

    [2016-06-13] => Array
        (
            [C] => 1
            [afterpay] => 
            [paypal] => 
            [Bank] => 
            [Ideal] => 
            [Afterpay] => 1
        )

    [2016-06-12] => Array
        (
            [C] => 1
            [afterpay] => 
            [paypal] => 
            [Bank] => 
            [Ideal] => 
        )

    [2016-06-14] => Array
        (
            [C] => 1
            [afterpay] => 
            [paypal] => 
            [Bank] => 
            [Ideal] => 
            [Afterpay] => 1
        )
)
```

but it's difficult me to find a way to count the payment method numbers and assign it

Example for **2016-07-07 array should be C= 2,Paypal = 1, Bank = 1**

```
[2016-07-07] => Array
            (
                [C] => 2
                [afterpay] => 
                [paypal] => 
                [Bank] => 1
                [Ideal] => 
                [Paypal] => 1
            )
```

can someone help me to add some code for get sum of payment methods and assign, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `array_merge` override the data if 2 keys are the same - what you need is to add all fields.

First, change `$array1` with init field as `0` instead of `null`.

Second, in your `array_walk`, replace `$array2[$a] = array_merge($array2[$a], $v);` with:

```
foreach($v as $k => $v)
    $array2[$a][$k] += $v;
```

This way you will add up each category

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it's not using array_map, you mean replace current array_merge  with array_map

Answer (score 0):

We need to increase Payment Method instead of merge array, to prevent overwrite old value.
Below code working for me

```
<?php
$shipment = [
    [
        'Datum' => '2016-07-07',
        'C' => 1,
    ],
    [
        'Datum' => '2016-07-07',
        'C' => 1,
    ],
    [
        'Datum' => '2016-07-07',
        'Paypal' => 1,
    ],
    [
        'Datum' => '2016-07-07',
        'Bank' => 1,
    ],
    [
        'Datum' => '2016-07-12',
        'Bank' => 1,
    ],
];

$template = ['C' => 0, 'Afterpay' => 0, 'Paypal' => 0, 'Bank' => 0, 'Ideal' => 0];
$result = [];

array_walk($shipment, function ($v) use (&$result, $template) {
    // Init by Datum if it is not in array
    $date = $v['Datum'];
    if (!isset($result[$date])) {
        $result[$date] = $template;
    }

    // Unset Datum to get final payment method only
    unset($v['Datum']);
    $itemKey = array_keys($v)[0];

    // Increase number
    $result[$date][$itemKey] += $v[$itemKey];
});

// Dump result
var_dump($result);
```